# JQuery: How to extract li items from div

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-selectors

I have the following div that contain an unordered list and other code:

```
<div id="myDiv">
    <ul>
       <div id="myInnerDiv">Here is a div</div>
       <li id="oneLi">One li</li>
       <script type="text/javascript">
           // some JS code
       </script>
       <li><span class="li-item">Some content 1</span></li>
       <li><span class="li-item">Some content 2</span></li>
       <li><span class="li-item">Some content 3</span></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I want to get the HTML corresponding to the latest `<li>` items after the `<script>` tag:

```
<ul>
    <li><span class="li-item">Some content 1</span></li>
    <li><span class="li-item">Some content 2</span></li>
    <li><span class="li-item">Some content 3</span></li>
</ul>
```

or just the li item:

```
<li><span class="li-item">Some content 1</span></li>
<li><span class="li-item">Some content 2</span></li>
<li><span class="li-item">Some content 3</span></li>
```

Do you know how to reach that with jQuery?

Comment: The source markup is invalid. `<div>`s are not allowed as children of an `<ul>` element ([MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/ul)).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can select the elements after another element by using the [`Next Siblings Selector (~)`](https://api.jquery.com/next-siblings-selector/)

You can also use [`.nextAll()`](https://api.jquery.com/nextAll/) to achieve the same - `$('#myDiv script').nextAll('li')`

I've also used [`.clone()`](https://api.jquery.com/clone/) to safely use [`.wrapAll('<ul>')`](https://api.jquery.com/wrapAll/) on the returned element without effecting the DOM

```js
// Returns a jQuery object containing the three <li> items after script
// Then clone ( to leave DOM as is ) and wrap with <ul>
const $listElements = $('#myDiv script ~ li').clone().wrapAll('<ul>');

// Get HTML of <ul>
const listHTML = $listElements.parent().prop('outerHTML');
console.log(listHTML);

// Get HTML of just <li>
const itemHTML = $listElements.parent().html();
console.log(itemHTML);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="myDiv">
  <ul>
    <div id=" myInnerDiv ">Here is a div</div>
    <li id="oneLi ">One li</li>
    <script type="text/javascript ">
      // some JS code
    </script>
    <li><span class="li-item ">Some content 1</span></li>
    <li><span class="li-item ">Some content 2</span></li>
    <li><span class="li-item ">Some content 3</span></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Just a note that jQuery calls it the [Next Siblings Selector](https://api.jquery.com/next-siblings-selector/), which actually sounds a lot more accurate than the CSS name.

Comment: Ah, thank you! I'll start referring to it by that because yeah, it makes more sense

Comment: If you add a `.wrapAll("<ul>")` the result is exactly what OP wants

Comment: How would you wrap the selection, without updating the page? I was thinking .clone() but not sure if that's the best way

Comment: It works, thank you. I reached the same with `nextAll()` but how to get the HTML of the list of `li` items without the loop?

Comment: @smartmouse I've updated my answer, is this what you were looking for now?

Comment: Thank you! Anyway you can leave the first solution as well in your aswer.

Comment: Not sure; they're returning strings so don't see what the issue could be past something off in your code

Answer (score -1):

Assuming you want the content of the latest list item:

`$("#myDiv ul li:last").text()`

Comment: _"I want to get the HTML corresponding to the latest <li> items after the <script> tag"_

Comment: @freedomn-m The markup shown as "expected output" is clear enough. OP wants the "last"/three `<li>` elements after the `<script>` element.